# How to show query result with selectize.js in Django

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-templates, selectize.js

I want to the taking ajax response.then show  select list attribute in Django Template. I take  data with ajax request but select list components does not show result of query.I want to show result query when searching keyword.When page load doesn't  fill list. Just show searching key.I send success ajax request and callback to success response object How can I fix this problem

Response Object :
    {data: "[{"Code": "1001"}, {"Code": "1100"}]"}

Django Template

```
{% block body %}
{ % load bootstrap4 %} {# import bootstrap4/bootstrap3 #}
{% load i18n %}


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js">
 </script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.legacy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.legacy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.min.css.map" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.legacy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.legacy.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.legacy.min.css.map" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
 $(document).ready( function () { 
  $('#select_code').selectize({
valueField: 'code',
labelField: 'code',
searchField: 'code',
options: [],
create: true,
load: function(query, callback) {
    if (!query.length) return callback();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test/json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            q: query
        },
        error: function() {
            callback();
        },
        success: function(res) {
          console.log(res.data)
        callback(res.data)
        }
     });
    }
  });
})
</script>

<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">

    <select class="form-control" id="select_code" ></select>
 </div>
```

test_json.py

```
def test_kolon(request):
    q=request.GET.get('q')
    db = Test.objects.filter(
                       Q(code__icontains= q)
                    ).values('code')
 list_data_json = json.dumps(list(db))

 context={
      "data":list_data_json
 }
 return JsonResponse(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved question.

```
list_data_json = json.dumps(list(db))
```

Change the following code

```
list_data_json = jlist(db)
context=list_data_json
return JsonResponse(context,safe=False)
```